# Critical Error When Copying From char* to char* Using Custom String Copy Function

Tags: c++, string

```
 char** strSplit(const char* str, const char splitter)
 {
    unsigned long splitterCount = strSplitCount(str, splitter) + 1;

    char** result = new char*[splitterCount];

    unsigned long startRange = 0, endRange = 0;
    for (unsigned long i = 0; i < splitterCount; i++)
    {
         while (str[endRange] == splitter)
         {
             endRange++;
             startRange++;
         }
         while (str[endRange] != splitter && str[endRange] != '\0')
         {
             endRange++;
         }

         result[i] = new char[(endRange - startRange + 1)];

         strCopy(result[i], str);

         //     unsigned long indexOffset = 0;
         //     for (unsigned long j = startRange; j < endRange; j++)
         //     {
         //         if (str[j] != splitter)
         //         {
         //             result[i][indexOffset] = str[j];
         //         }
         //         indexOffset++;
         //     }
         //     result[i][indexOffset] = '\0';
         //
         //     startRange = ++endRange;
     }

     return result;
 }
```

This function takes in a const char* of a cstring and a const char of where to split within the string. The function correctly splits strings into a char** and returns it. To make the function look cleaner I made a strCopy function which works correctly outside this fucntion. But when strCopy is used within the function visual studio throws a critical error. But to make things even more interesting if you uncomment the commented code and remove the strCopy function the data gets copied correctly and no error is thrown. So why does my strCopy function not work?

```
 void strCopy(char* dest, const char* src)
 {
     while (*src)
     {
         *dest = *src;
         src++;
         dest++;
     }
     *dest = '\0';
 }
```

Comment: if you're using C++ then why tag C and use strcpy? Use `str::string` instead

Comment: C is not C++ is not C! Remove the unrelated tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this statement

```
result[i] = new char[(endRange - startRange + 1)];
```

It is clear that you need to copy `str` from `startRange` up to `endRange` and append the result string with the terminating zero.

However you are trying to copy all the string `str`.

```
strCopy(result[i], str);
```

You need to write a function either like `std::strncpy` or like `std::memcpy` and use it to copy substrings.

Comment: I would not even try to make sense of this completely obfuscated and broken algorithm. The preceding `while` loop advances `endRange` until it either finds the delimiter or `'\0`, so `startRange` has absolutely no meaningful role in this, whatsoever. Even if the algorithm gets adjusted in this manner, it will still be completely and totally broken, that's quite obvious.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I am sure that he bothers about his function strCopy and the shown code is not a real code.;) When he'll write the function he can ask a new question.:)